# Python Class variables not being initialized

Tags: python, class, variables

I have this class definition,  it is a datafile that will be read and a single column and sample rate information will be extracted.

```
class dataFile:
    def __init__(self, oldname, folName):
            self.name = oldname                 # Original File name
            self.nm_split = os.path.splitext(oldname)
            self.newName = str(self.nm_split[0] + "_trimmed" + self.nm_split[1]) 
            self.path = "./" + folName  ## Output Folder path
            self.y = []     ## Data to be extracted into list





        def readDat(self):       ## Extract the voltage column and put into array
            with open(self.name) as f:
                for line in f:
                    if line.startswith('%'):
                        if datafile.lookUp in line:
                            self.sRate = float(str.split(line)[3])
                        else:
                            continue

                    elif not len(line.strip()) ==0:
                        row = line.split()
                        self.y.append(float(row[2]))

                    else:
                        continue

            self.y = np.array(self.y);

            return self.y, self.sRate
```

When I run the program, and specifically the `readDat()` function, I get the following Message:

```
AttributeError: datafile instance has no attribute 'sRate'
```

Clearly it is defined within that first if statement in `readDat` so why isn't the interpreter seeing it?

Comment: Please fix the indentation.

Comment: Since `self.sRate` is not initialized to a value in the event that the if statements fail to locate a valid line then `self.sRate` will not be set.  Therefore the return statement tries to return `self.sRate` but it had never been set.  The `__init__` method should set a default for `self.sRate=None` so a value can always be returned.

Comment: Aahhh!  Thanks that solved it.  I thought I could just initialize it inside the if statement, shows what I know.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ifs before sRate is defined is not doing what you expect it to and sRate is never being declared.

I don't see a declaration for datfile.lookUp either:

```
            for line in f:
                if line.startswith('%'):
                    if datafile.lookUp in line: # <---- lookUp?
                        self.sRate = float(str.split(line)[3])
                    else:
                        continue
```

Consider declaring .sRate with a default value; it's not pythonic but it can avoid confusion.

Comment: Oh yea I copied only the readDat function.  lookup is defined outside of __init__ in the full code.  I'm sorry I missed that mistake.

Comment: if lookUp is a function it should be `if datafile.lookUp() in line:`